# Views in QML from Qt(main.cpp)

Tags: qt, file, view, qml

I have problem with change view/file in QML. In qrc file I have main.qml and second.qml. In main.cpp i start my app by code:

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl(("qrc:///main.qml")));
view.show();
```

In main.qml is button which should change view to second.qml, but I dont know in what way do it. I read about qml but anywhere i found the examples.

The main.qml:

```
Item {
id: screen; width: 320; height: 480;

signal exitApp()
signal qmlSignal(string addressIP, int portTCP)

Rectangle {
    id: background
    anchors.fill: parent; color: "#ffffff";
    anchors.rightMargin: 0
    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.topMargin: 0

    Button {
        id: loginBtn
        text: qsTr("RUN")
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 100
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 100
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 170
        anchors.top: tcpRow.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        onClicked: qmlSignal(addressIPTextField.text, parseInt(portTCPTextField.text))
     }
 }
    Row {
        id: tcpRow
        x: 8
        width: 309
        height: 100
        anchors.top: ipRow.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Label {
            id: portTCPLabel
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("Port TCP")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.right: portTCPTextField.left
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) to navigate between multiple "screens". To adapt your existing code to use `StackView`, it's probably easier to move each screen into its own QML file. For example, move the `background` item into `LoginScreen.qml`:

```
Rectangle {
    id: background

    // ...

    Button {
        onClicked: {
            qmlSignal(addressIPTextField.text, parseInt(portTCPTextField.text));
            StackView.view.push("qrc:/second.qml");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we use the attached `view` property of `StackView` to get access to the view and then push the second screen onto it.

Then, in `main.qml`:

```
Window {
     width: // ...
     height: // ...

     StackView {
         initialItem: LoginScreen {}
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what mean `StackView.view` ? It's view from main.cpp ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it's an attached property of `StackView`. Please read the documentation I linked to.